# Multiple jQuery versions in one page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have used `jQuery 1.10` for `datePicker` and `jQuery 1.9` for `TimePicker` (from fgelinas.com).

I used `noConflict();` but not useful. Here is my code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Admin/time-picker/include/ui-1.10.0/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Admin/time-picker/jquery.ui.timepicker.css?v=0.3.3" type="text/css" />

<script src="~/Content/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Admin/time-picker/include/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Admin/time-picker/include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Admin/time-picker/include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Admin/time-picker/include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.tabs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Admin/time-picker/include/ui-1.10.0/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Admin/time-picker/jquery.ui.timepicker.js?v=0.3.3"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
    $.noConflict();
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        constrainInput: true,
        yearRange: "1999:2025",
        onSelect: function () {
            alert($('#datepicker').val());
        }
    });
</script>

<div>
    <label for="timepicker.[1]">Default time picker :</label>
    <input type="text" style="width: 70px;" id="timepicker.[1]" value="" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#timepicker\\.\\[1\\]').timepicker({
                showAnim: 'blind'
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" />
</div>
```

When I tried to `$.noConflict()` in `timePicker`, it does not let use any of the control. But above code just lets use `datePicker`. When I remove `datePicker` script, `timePicker` runs perfectly. I have to use both of them in one page. Help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use one version only? Is the timepicker/datepicker not present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) documentation there is an option to save the previous jQuery into a variable like this:
`var j = $.noConflict();`
So where you want to use the firstly loaded jQuery version you can use the dollar sign, but if you need the lastly loaded then you need to use `j`.

In your current code you load the jquery libraries 1.10 first then 1.9 and call the noConflict so the dollar sign is hold the 1.10 jquery version.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
    var lastJQuery = $.noConflict();
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        constrainInput: true,
        yearRange: "1999:2025",
        onSelect: function () {
            alert($('#datepicker').val());
        }
    });
</script>

<div>
    <label for="timepicker.[1]">Default time picker :</label>
    <input type="text" style="width: 70px;" id="timepicker.[1]" value="" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        lastJQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('#timepicker\\.\\[1\\]').timepicker({
                showAnim: 'blind'
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: this allows `datePicker` but not `timePicker`.

Comment: It works fine for me.
Do you changed this line: `lastJQuery(document).ready(function ($) {` notice that the ready event handler function dollar sign parameter. This parameter will be the `j`

Comment: oops. i missed `$`... Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `$(selector).datepicker(options)` 
and `$(selector).timepicker(options)` calls to the bottom of your page .. also, i found some weird behavior with $.noConflict() .. is  this necessary?

**Updated:** [this might work for you?](http://plnkr.co/edit/ccAUfkSWPnR8M38aLLMx?p=preview)